# GSA feed - adding multiple documents to a single record

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am working on a product catalog whose search is powered by GSA. Each product is a single entry, but may have many associated documents. As I see there is only one content node allowed in the feed XML. is there a way to add multiple files to same record in the feed xml?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please explain in a bit more detail what you are trying to achieve? You can add references to other records as metadata but one record = one document in the index.

Comment: The product specification is not a single file. There is a document for sales pitch, anther with detailed specifications and may even have another with customer reference/case study. The application being a product catalog ultimately, it needs to show only one search result per product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is going be when submitting each record to the feed, is to extract the content of associated documents and add as additional meta-data before sending to the feed.

Alternately, you can submit each record and each document, with some meta-data that references the record it's associated with. When returning search results, you could customize the front-end results to display related content (records or other attached documents).

Comment: The downside of submitting multiple records is the relevancy score and the response time (application needs to de-duplicate the results prior to display) Another approach we are trying out is the concatenating of text from multiple files, albeit from limited file formats.

Comment: I agree with Ed. Put the additional content on the record as additional metadata. You might not fit all of the content but if you really have to combine it all that's the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try additional document content into new metadata(1500 char limit) or document body.